# Android: How to use existing graphic elements

Tags: android, uiimageview, reusability

I would like to create a user interface which would contain network indication icons (3G, WiFi...) and I would like to use existing graphic elements which are displayed in notification bar.

Does anyone know how to get these existing elements and use it in custom layout?

I guess these icons are all ImageView elements and I am wondering whether it is possible to retrieve them with `findViewById()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are drawables in android.R.drawable. There is a list of avaiable drawables for 1.0 at [drawable list](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/info/android_drawables/android_drawables.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can go to http://source.android.com/download to get instructions on how to download Android sources (images/drawables included), search for *.pngs and then reference the ones you need like this: getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save).

P.S. At least some of the drawables come with sdk: $SDK_PATH\platforms\android-1.5\data\res\drawable